# Nested Group By (a group by within a group by)

Tags: python

I'm just wondering is it possible that I can use python to get a group by within another group by? Let's say I have a list of tuple:

```
[
('Simon', 'Brown', 'Playing computer games', 'USA', 'New York City', '2022-01-02', 'Win'),
('Simon', 'Brown', 'Playing computer games', 'USA', 'San Francisco City', '2022-01-03', 'Lose'),
('Simon', 'Brown', 'Playing piano games', 'China', 'Beijing City', '2022-01-02', 'Lose'),
('Simon', 'Brown', 'Playing piano games', 'China', 'Shanghai City', '2022-01-03', 'Lose'),
('Simon', 'Brown', 'Playing piano games', 'Australia', 'Sydney City', '2022-01-03', 'Lose'),
('Trudy', 'Porter', 'Playing piano games', 'Australia', 'Sydney City', '2022-01-03', 'Lose')
]
```

Is it possible to get the results like the following (it's  more like firstly group by based on the first and second item in each tuple, and then within each group, further group by based on the third and fourth items, and then list the rest of the items of each tuple in each line-- with space):

```
Simon Brown
Playing computer games-USA
New York City            2022-01-02              Win
San Francisco City       2022-01-03              Lose

Playing piano games  China
Beijing City             2022-01-02              Lose
Shanghai City            2022-01-03              Lose

Playing piano games Australia
Sydney City             2022-01-03               Lose

Trudy Porter 
Playing piano games Australia
Sydney City             2022-01-03                Lose
```

[image]

Comment: the expected result is not clear…

Comment: So it's more about finding the same first and second items from a list of tuples and then group them by. After that, within each group, further group by based on the same items in the rest of the list of tuples.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please check https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @pythonlearner , so basically what you want is to group common elements and the group uncommon element?

Comment: can you diaplay expected result clearly and in what data structure?

Comment: @ 
Faraaz Kurawle  

Yes and no.

I want to group common elements first and then further group the rest of the comment elements. After that, display the rest of the items per line based on the tuple. 

For example, if there are two tuples share the first, second, third, and fourth items. Then I want to group those two tuples by displaying the common first and second items. Then within each group, further group the third and fourth items. After that, display the rest of the items.

Comment: First item Second item
third item-fourth item
fifth different item  sixth different item seventh different item
another fifth different item  another sixth different item another seventh different item
a different First item  a different Second item
a different third item- a different fourth item
a further different fifth different item  sixth different item seventh different item
another fifth different item  another sixth different item another seventh different item

Comment: Hi everyone, I've just edited my post to make it more clear. I hope it seems better now.

Comment: What is the original data set where you got showed results from?

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it be possible? What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 2):

There's a [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) tool in the standard library, which you could use in combination with [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) as key-function. You'd get something like this:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

data = [<your list>]

for key1, group1 in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0, 1)):
    print(*key1)
    for key2, group2 in groupby(group1, key=itemgetter(2, 3)):
        print("\t", *key2)
        for items in group2:
            print("\t\t", *items[4:])
```

This prints:

```
Simon Brown
     Playing computer games USA
         New York City 2022-01-02 Win
         San Francisco City 2022-01-03 Lose
     Playing piano games China
         Beijing City 2022-01-02 Lose
         Shanghai City 2022-01-03 Lose
     Playing piano games Australia
         Sydney City 2022-01-03 Lose
Trudy Porter
     Playing piano games Australia
         Sydney City 2022-01-03 Lose
```

---

If you want to format `datetime` objects (here at index 5) then you could adjust that to

```
from datetime import datetime
...
        ...
        for items in group2:
            print("\t\t", *(
                    item.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") if isinstance(item, datetime)
                    else item for item in items[4:]
                )
            )
```

Edit: Adjusted according to **@KellyBundy's** hint.

Comment: Thanks, but when I try to run it, the system says "'key1' is an invalid keyword argument for groupby()"

Comment: @pythonlearner That sounds more like a copy-and-paste error etc.: When I use the fixed list you provide (there's a `)` missing at the end of the last tuple) as `data` and run the code it works?

Comment: @pythonlearner I don't use `key1=...` in a `groupby()`, only `key=...`, so this error sounds strange to me?

Comment: Can I ask what should I do if there's a datatime type? The code wouldn't work if there's a datetime type in it.

Comment: @pythonlearner I don't see a reason why `datatime`  would make a difference. Could be a bit more specific about what exactly isn't working in this case?

Comment: @pythonlearner Is it the printing (conversion to string) that is making problems?

Comment: If you print like `print("\t", *key2)` etc, you wouldn't need to convert to strings yourself.

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes, indeed, thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. May I ask is it possible to:
1. instead of printing all the rest of the items in group2 as in print("\t\t", *items[4:]), can I just print some of them by using group2[4],group2[8], etc? I tried to change it to print("\t\t", *group2[4], *group2[6]). But it's not working....

2. Is it possible that I can make the results of those codes have a format (more visually appealing). Like all the dates are all in the same position? thanks

Comment: Followed by the last thread.

 For example, the positions of the dates simply rely on the length of the previous item, but I don't want that. I want every item in the result grid has the same position so it wouldn't look really messy.  Thanks

Comment: Can I also ask another question? If I wanna apply what you put there to something different (but very similar). At this time, I only want to group first and then print out the rest of it.

I changed the codes to:

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
    data = dbWinning
    for key, group in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0)): #group by the 0 position
        print(*key)
        for items in group:
            print("\t\t", *group[1:])
But it didn't work: TypeError: 'itertools._grouper' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @pythonlearner Regarding `group2[4]` etc.: The group part of the `groupby` return is not a sequence (list etc.), it's an iterator. So if you want index access then convert it into a list: `group2 = list(group2)`.

Comment: @pythonlearner  This `for items in group: print("\t\t", *group[1:])` doesn't really makes sense: Don't you want `print("\t\t", *items[1:])` instead?

Comment: @pythonlearner Regarding the formatted printing: All is possible, but that's a vast field and seems beyond the scope of this specific question.

Comment: @Timus Thank you for the explanation. I changed that to print("\t\t", *items[1:]. However, it's still not working (TypeError: 'itertools._grouper' object is not subscriptable). I am just wondering I can apply to what you've suggested to groupby only once instead of groupby within a groupby? 
  from itertools import groupby
    from operator import itemgetter
    data = database
    for key, group in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0)):
        print(*key)
        for items in group:
            print("\t\t", *group[1:])

Comment: @pythonlearner You can't do this `group[1:]` unless you have converted `group` to a list (or another sequence).

Comment: @Timus I see, thanks. Python is just soo complicated for me, still struggling with some most basic stuff. Thank you so much for everything, and I now know what to do

Answer (score 0):

This should work as long as you don't have any outcomes with the same player, date, location and activity:

```
import pandas as pd

d = [<your list>]
c = ['First', 'Last', 'Activity', 'Country', 'City', 'Date', 'Outcome']
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d, columns = c)
df.pivot(index = c[:5], columns = c[-2]).stack()
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help. before that, I thought panda could only be used in dictionary.